# populate data in iphone dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.LoadFile count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}
 int title =0;

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    for (title = 0 ; title <= section; title++)
    {
        NSLog(@"section - %d ",title);
        NSDictionary *dict = [LoadFile objectAtIndex:title];
        NSString *titlename = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",titlename);
        if (section == title)
            return titlename;
    }
}
```

Here i am using two arrays which is created on the page itself,in this case it will work fine but for the case when i need it to populate from DB then what should i do.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    while (i < sec)
    {


    dict = [LoadFile objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *addr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"address"]];
    NSString *con = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"contact"]];
    NSString *sal = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"salary"]];
    NSString *tec = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"tech"]];       

    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:addr,con,sal,tec,nil];
  // NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:i,i,i,i,nil];
      //NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"12",@"22",@"32",@"42",nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    if(indexPath.section == i)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        i++;
    }


}
    return cell;
}

    for (i = 0 ; i <= sec-1; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"section - %d ",title);
        NSDictionary *dict = [LoadFile objectAtIndex:title];
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        { 
            UILabel *Address = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,9, 200, 20)];
            Address.textColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
            Address.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [Address setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
            [Address setTag:i];
            Address.text = [dict objectForKey:@"address"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:Address];
            UILabel *tech = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,9, 200, 20)];
            tech.textColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
            tech.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [tech setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
            [tech setTag:i];
            tech.text = [dict objectForKey:@"tech"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:tech];

        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {

            UILabel *tech = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,9, 200, 20)];
            tech.textColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
            tech.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [tech setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
            [tech setTag:i];
            tech.text = [dict objectForKey:@"tech"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:tech];
          }
   }
   else if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        UILabel *contact = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,9, 200, 20)];
        contact.textColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
        contact.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [contact setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
        contact.text = [dict objectForKey:@"contact"];
        // NSLog(@"Val-%@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
        [contact setTag:-4];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contact];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        UILabel *salary = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,9, 200, 20)];
        salary.textColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
        salary.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [salary setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
        salary.text = [dict objectForKey:@"salary"];
        // NSLog(@"Val-%@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
        [salary setTag:-4];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:salary];
    }
    else
    {
        UILabel *tech = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,9, 200, 20)];
        tech.textColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
        tech.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [tech setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
        tech.text = [dict objectForKey:@"tech"];
        // NSLog(@"Val-%@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
        [tech setTag:-4];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tech];
}
```

I want to populate data from table in database ,dynamically

Comment: What do you mean "populate from a DB"?

Comment: What are you trying to do?...

Comment: Actually i want to fetch the information from sqllite db and show it in tableview in grouprd style . No. Records in database can   be changed dynamically . so how can i show data for a row in cells in particular  section.Hope u understand wht i ma tring to say

Comment: Are you using CoreData? How are use fetching this information?

Comment: Connection from database and query part i have done in other class .after tht i got ,y requested data in a mutable array  i.e. "loadfile" in this case .

Comment: Is loadfile a mutable array which hold the data from db as a NSDictionary?

Comment: Yes loadfile is a mutable array .

Comment: Can you post your data structure and how would you want to display? (Fot my understanding, you want to show the data with different section group by address/tech/contact/salary etc. Is it like that?)

Comment: share [g+] share [fb] share [tw]
 

My DataBase Table Structure:

Name ,Address ,Contact ,Salary ,Tech (column names)

// How i want to display : Table View Grouped Style: Section1 cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4

section2
cell1
cell2
cell3
cell4

for ex.

John (section1 - name field)
  NewYork(cell1 - address field)
  9999999(cell2 - contact field)
  12000$ (cell3 - salary field)
  Iphone (cell4 - tech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your array has been updated with new data, you just call [self.tableview reloadData];

Comment: My DataBase Table Structure:

Name ,Address ,Contact ,Salary ,Tech (column names)

// How i want to display : Table View Grouped Style: Section1 cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4

section2
cell1
cell2
cell3
cell4

for ex.

John (section1 - name field)
  NewYork(cell1 - address field)
  9999999(cell2 - contact field)
  12000$ (cell3 - salary field)
  Iphone (cell4 - tech)

Comment: Well you could use switch statements or if then else statements. then based on the section number and the row number set the contents of the cell according to what you want in there. So if Section 0 Row 0 cell.textLabel.text = Name

Comment: But now when i rolls up and down the table the cell values chnges their places...wht should i do to get rid of it

Comment: Your implementation must have a new problem. Edit the question and show us your new code.

Comment: Can you please mark the question as answered if it answered your question?